# R - regsubsets leaps package crashes R. Suspect missing dependencies?

Tags: r, machine-learning, package, ubuntu-14.04

The facts:

1. Using code that works for other people, my code fails on the following line:

   ```
   fit.bsub <- regsubsets(x=x.trn ,y=y.trn, intercept=FALSE);
   ```
2. It told me the following error:

   ```
   Error in leaps.setup(x, y, wt = weights, nbest = nbest, nvmax = nvmax, 
   : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 3)
   ```
3. So I added the weights parameter and the error in (2) went away:

   ```
   fit.bsub <- regsubsets(x=x.trn, y=y.trn, weights=rep(1,length(y.trn)), 
   intercept=FALSE);
   ```
4. Now instead of getting an error, I get the following:

   ```
   Error in leaps.setup(x, y, wt = weights, nbest = nbest, nvmax = nvmax,  
   : wt and x different lengths
   ```
5. Then, R crashes after a few seconds.

I suspect there is a missing dependency but I have no idea how to diagnose what I need. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and R 3.1.2. Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Files requested:

http://lillian-ashmore.com/test/data/author_training.csv

http://lillian-ashmore.com/test/data/author_training_y.csv

http://lillian-ashmore.com/test/data/author_testing.csv

http://lillian-ashmore.com/test/data/author_testing_y.csv

Comment: Can you give us a reproducible example? I want to run that, but I don't have x.trn, y.trn, etc.  Also, include the library() calls so we know what packages you are using.

Comment: Sure thing! See the URLs in the edited blurb above!